# How to install pyqt5-sip on windows x86

Tags: python, pip, pyqt5, spyder

So, basically i was installing spyder ide..
and an error came..
[image]

so.. it can be simply fixed with visual c++ 14.0 and above..
but.. i don't want to download that many gb long visual studio's stuffs..
any whl file for that?
because i know that whl file can be its solution..
and there are no whl file for win32 on the pypi page..

```
SPECS:
OS: Windows 7 SP1
Python: 3.8.10
ARCH: x86 (32 bit)
```

EDIT: gladly, i installed a previous version of PyQt5-sip!

Comment: Why not use python for 64 bit?

Comment: @eyllanesc i have a 32 bit machine

Answer (score 0):

PyQt5-sip 12.8.1 can run on windows x86